# Geopandas Overlay Union does not find all Overlaps

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, overlay

I am trying to union 4 polygons and want to know for each (sub)region, which of the 4 polygons are overlapping. My idea was to use `geopandas.overlay(..)` iteratively.
The code looks like this:

```py
union = None

for i in range(4):
    # Shapely Polygon
    polygon = list_of_polygons[i]  
            
    gs = gpd.GeoSeries(polygon)
    
    # Give each Polygon its index as identifier
    df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': gs, str(i): [True]})

    print(df)
 
    if union is None:
        union = df
    else:
        res = gpd.tools.overlay(union, df, how='union', keep_geom_type=True)  
        union = res

print(union)
```

This gives me for the 4 polygons

```
                                            geometry     0
0  POLYGON ((0.42565 2.00000, -3.21000 8.33000, -...  True

                                            geometry     1
0  POLYGON ((-3.29000 8.33000, 1.50000 8.33000, 1...  True

                                            geometry     2
0  POLYGON ((-1.69946 -3.69930, 1.00000 1.00000, ...  True

                                            geometry     3
0  POLYGON ((0.00714 -6.96842, -0.00201 -6.96432,...  True
```

and for the union-dataframe

```
      0     1     2     3                                           geometry
0  True   NaN  True  True  MULTIPOLYGON (((2.00000 2.00000, 5.14000 2.000...
1  True   NaN   NaN  True  MULTIPOLYGON (((4.03834 -1.03834, 5.35000 -2.3...
2   NaN  True   NaN  True  POLYGON ((-1.64000 8.33000, -0.79000 8.33000, ...
3  True   NaN  True   NaN  POLYGON ((-1.69789 -3.69773, 0.42570 -0.00000,...
4  True  True   NaN   NaN  MULTIPOLYGON (((0.42565 2.00000, -3.21000 8.33...
5  True   NaN   NaN   NaN  MULTIPOLYGON (((-1.51000 -11.52000, -1.51000 -...
6   NaN  True   NaN   NaN  MULTIPOLYGON (((-0.79000 8.33000, 1.50000 8.33...
7   NaN   NaN  True   NaN  MULTIPOLYGON (((8.79000 8.33000, 9.77000 8.330...
8   NaN   NaN   NaN  True  MULTIPOLYGON (((9.77000 -0.00000, 9.77000 -10....
```

In theory, each row contains one region of the union and `True`/`NaN` if the corresponding polygon (0, 1, 2, or 3) overlaps there or not.
However, the plot of the resulting 9 (multi-)polygons is not congruent with the plot of the union of the original 4 polygons.
The plots of polygons 0 - 3 and their overlayed plot are as follows:
[image: Plot of Polygon 0]

[image: Plot of Polygon 1]

[image: Plot of Polygon 2]

[image: Plot of Polygon 3]

[image: Overlaid Plot of all Polygons 0-3]

Whereas the plot of all 9 (multi-)polygons looks like this (each color represents a different overlap, white areas indicate missing regions):

[image: Plot of the (Multi-)Polygons]

Am I missing something, or is that an error of `geopandas.overlay`?

What would I need to change to get the desired outcome?

---

I still do not know why geopandas behaves that way, but using @rickD 's comment I found a workaround using `intersection` and `difference` from `shapely`.

```py
# Contains a tuple of a shapely object 
# And a list of indices of the polygons which overlap there 
sub_division = [(list_of_polygons[0], [0])]

for i in range(1, len(list_of_polygons)):
    tmp = []
    
    polygon = list_of_polygons[i]

    # For every new polygon, loop over the list of existing (sub)regions
    # And compute the intersection and differences
    for (sub_region, indices) in sub_division:

        intersection = sub_region.intersection(polygon)
        difference = sub_region.difference(polygon)
        polygon = polygon.difference(sub_region)

        tmp.append((intersection, indices + [i]))        
        tmp.append((difference, indices))

    tmp.append((polygon, [i]))
    sub_division = tmp
```

Now, `sub_division` contains all (sub)regions where polygons in `list_of_polygons` overlap, together with their indices.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you're going for here, but seeing as you are starting w/ Shapely polys, might be best to just use their `union` to get what you want and then stuff it into a GeoDataFrame. https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.union

Comment: @rickD I'd like to overlay 4 polygons over each other, and want to know for each of the resulting subregions, which of the polygons are intersecting. As far as I understand, the shapely union of two objects a, b only returns one object with the shape of (a or b). What I'd like to have are the separate polygons (a minus b), (a and b), and (b minus a), extended to 4 polygons.

Comment: you should be able to get what you need w/ using `union`, `difference`, and/or `symmetrical_difference`. As you iterate, you can create whatever resulting data you then want to see in your GeoDataFrame.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Unfortunately, I can't upvote your comment yet :(